# How to install ubuntu on SSD and windows 10 on HDD

Tags: dual-boot, server, hard-drive, ssd, windows-10

I'm using ubuntu 22.04 LTS installed in SSD (128Gb) and windows 10 installed in HDD (1 Tb). So my question is I want to switch to some other distro, is possible to just format and install the new linux on SSD while the HDD with windows 10 stays untouched??

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, yes, if you install an OS on the SSD, the grub screen should allow you to choose the OS you want to boot, and it should show both Windows (on HDD) and the OS on the SSD.